# Spring Boot JPA - Define a One to Many relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

i'm trying to build a simple full stack tic-tac-toe application, but i've some problem defing a one-to-many relationship.

here the context, we have a main table Games:

```
CREATE TABLE `tictactoe`.`games` (
  `idgames` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gridConf` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `playerNum` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idgames`));
```

and a secondary table, Gamesteps:

```
CREATE TABLE `tictactoe`.`gamesteps1` (
  `idgamesteps` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idgame` INT NOT NULL,
  `step` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idgamesteps`));
```

i'd like to define a relation One (Game) to Many (Gamesteps),
where the combo Gamesteps.idgamesteps and Gamesteps.games is primary key on the Gamesteps table.

i have two doubts:

1- how should i define my db tables? are my queries rights or do i need an explict foreing key?

2 -JPA annotations:
here my entities:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Games {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer idgames;

    private String gridConf;

    private Integer playerNum;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idgames")
    private Set<GameSteps> gameSteps;

//all setter/getters
```

secondary table:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class GameSteps {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer idGameSteps;

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "idgames", referencedColumnName = "idgames")
     private Integer idgame;

    private String step;

//all setter/getter
```

i'm trying to archive is the possibility to do a Save/findAll operation throught my CRUDRepository interface on the main entity (Games) and do an automatic Save/findAll on all the others subEntities (gamesteps).

for me is not clear where i should use the `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToOne` annotations.
For now i'm only getting exceptions.

if needs others info just ask, any type of help / documentation will be really approciated!

Thanks!

---

Following @Smutje comment i've change to:

```
public class GameSteps {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer idGameSteps;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idgames", referencedColumnName = "idgames")
private **Games** idgame;
```

and

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "**idgame**")
private Set<GameSteps> gameSteps;
```

but got:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'idgames' in 'field list'
```

Comment: What kind of exceptions do you get? Also, replace `private Integer idgame` with `private Games game` and change the `mapppedBy` value of `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "idgames")` to the value of the field in `GameSteps`.

Comment: I recommend reading this guide on compsite key https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-composite-primary-keys

Comment: ASAP i will post the exception of the various cases i've tried, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

If you want Gamesteps.idgamesteps and Gamesteps.games to be primary key on the Gamesteps table. You have to use the tags @EmbeddedId and @Embeddable, your composite key has to be another class.

> The primary key fields are defined in an embeddable class. The entity contains a single primary key field that is annotated with @EmbeddedId and contains an instance of that embeddable class.

Something like this

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class GameSteps {

    @EmbeddedId
    private GameStepsPK pk;

    private String step;

// getters and setters
```

GameStepsPK would be the composite key

```
    import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Embeddable
public class ExploitationEvaluationPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer idGameSteps;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idgames", referencedColumnName = "idgames")
    private Games idgames;
```

You can also read about this [here](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id)

I hope this helps